# best way to pair list of titles with a separate list of their corresponding links? (bs4)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, hyperlink

**final edit: so here's the solution -**

```
list_c = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(titleList, linkList)]
```

**Original post**: I used bs4 to scrape a recipe website where the title to each recipe is not saved within the link tag. so I've extracted the titles of the recipes from one part of the code, and extracted the links from the other part and I've got these two lists (recipes, links) but I'm not sure the best way to pair each title to its corresponding link.

(The end goal is to have the titles be hyperlinked in an HTML file that I will put on my eventual recipe aggregator website).

I was considering saving them to a dictionary as key value pairs, or something else(?), so that I can call them into the HTML doc later on.

suggestions?

EDIT:
here's the code, works fine

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('article')

linkList = []
titleList = []

for link in links[0:12]:
    hyperL = link.find('header', class_ = 'entry-header').a['href']
    linkList.append(hyperL)
for title in links:
        x = title.get('aria-label')
        titleList.append(x)
```

linkList prints out something like

```
['www.recipe.com/ham', 'www.recipe.com/curry', 'www.recipe.com/etc']
```

and

```
titleList is ['Ham', 'Curry', 'etc']
```

I want to print a list from these 2 like this:

```
[['Ham', 'www.recipe.com/ham'],['Curry', 'www.recipe.com/curry']]
```

The final goal for my website, I would want to have the following for each pair:

```
 <a href='www.recipe.com/ham'>Ham<a/>
```

Comment: Can you share some example of what data you have and what kind of output you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you only anticipate looking up titles, and then using the result links, dictionaries are great for that.

Comment: Right but I'm just having trouble with how to code an item from one list into a key-value pair that corresponds with the item with the same index in the 2nd. like how to get {titleList[0]:linkList[0]}

Comment: And obviously I could write {titleList[0]:linkList[0]} for each index but I'm going to have dozens of recipes and links and I'm having trouble figuring out that code. But I'm like right there... will probably figure it out here soon